Swagger's requestInterceptor with Python (FAST API)
I have configured the swagger using FAST API for my project , Now I would like to intercept the request coming out of swagger UI . In swagger documentation I see a parameter requestInterceptor can be used for such task , but when ever I am starting my app with below mentioned code , Swagger UI starts giving me error "s.requestInterceptor is not a function /openapi.json" , I tried looking for the solution but found None
app = FastAPI(
swagger_ui_parameters={"requestSnippetsEnabled": True,"persistAuthorization":True,
                       "requestInterceptor": """
       (req) => {
           // Modify the request object as needed
           req.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer <your_access_token>';
           return req;
       }
   """
                       }

)

Have you looked at what gets rendered for the swagger initialization object? (i.e. how the given parameters gets rendered)

Since requestinterceptor is a JavaScript function (which does not have the corresponding Python data type), you'll probably need to inject it directly into Swagger UI's HTML by overriding FastAPI's get_swagger_ui_html  function - see example here.

What you are trying to do is https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/
To implement that you can follow https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/how-to/extending-openapi/
then:
    openapi_schema["components"]["securitySchemes"] = {
        "apiKey": {
            "type": "apiKey",
            "in": "header",
            "name": "BEARER",
        },
         "bearerAuth":   {         # arbitrary name for the security scheme
            "type": "http",
            "scheme": "bearer",
            "bearerFormat": "JWT"
        }
    }
    openapi_schema["security"] = [
        {"apiKey": ["read", "write"], "bearerAuth": ["read", "write"]}
    ]

apikey header strategy is another option:
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/
